# Separation from URL the scrape of text

Tags: postgresql

I have a some URL like this:

`http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article?AID=/20140128/XXX/140129527`

and want to separate this scrape of text

```
20140128/XXX/140129527
```

but only when URL have this scrape of text

```
article?AID=/
```

I have tried function "substring" but all of my options were wrong. What's more sometimes url doesn't end like this, but have sign & etc., like this

`http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article?AID=/20140128/XXX/140129527&photo1`

and I also want to separate the same scrape of text without `&photo1`

Do you have any idea? This scrape of text `'XXX/140129527'` hasdifferent length. I really couldn't find the solution of this problem on stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE meuk
        ( total varchar
        , base_url varchar
        , rest_url varchar
        );
INSERT INTO meuk(total) VALUES
('http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article?AID=/20140128/XXX/140129527')
        ;
```

You could use [regexp_replace()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) :

```
UPDATE meuk
SET base_url = regexp_replace(total, E'([^?]+)?AID=(.+)', E'\\1' )
        -- , rest_url = regexp_replace(total, E'http://.+\?AID=/(.+)', E'\\1' )
        , rest_url = regexp_replace(total, E'http://.+\?AID=/([^&]+)(.*)$', E'\\1' )
        ;

SELECT * FROM meuk;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 1
                                   total                                   |                    base_url                    |        rest_url        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------
 http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article?AID=/20140128/XXX/140129527 | http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article? | 20140128/XXX/140129527
(1 row)
```

Comment: http://www.newspaper.pl/abcd/bcda.dll/article?AID=/20140128/XXX/140129527&photo1 and what's about this url...I also want the same solution 20140128/XXX/140129527 ??